# Is it safe to add indexes after checking for missing indexes?

Tags: mysql

Is it safe to add indexes after checking for missing indexes? Or is there some additional checks I need to make before adding indexes to get a performance boost from the server?

Ran this after I found that 100,000+ queries had join without indexes:

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,t.TABLE_NAME
    ,c.COLUMN_NAME
    ,IFNULL(kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 'Not indexed') AS Indexed
FROM information_schema.TABLES as t
INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS as c
    ON c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%_id'
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as kcu
    ON kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        AND kcu.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME
        AND kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION = 1
WHERE kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL
AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('information_schema', 'performance_schema', 'mysql');
```

And got the following:

```
"pr_main"   "work_incident" "ReportID"  "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_hmwp_ms_intrusions" "user_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_usermeta"   "user_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_banner_images"  "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_termmeta"   "term_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_commentmeta"    "comment_id"    "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_comments"   "comment_post_ID"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_comments"   "user_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_postmeta"   "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_mtouchquiz_question"    "quiz_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_mtouchquiz_answer"  "question_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_mf_post_meta"   "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_redirection_items"  "group_id"  "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_product"    "id"    "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_pr_product_reservation" id" "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_pr_product_favorite_count"  "id"    "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_term_relationships" "term_taxonomy_id"  "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_product_score"  "id"    "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_posts"  "guid"  "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_mtouchquiz_ratings" "quiz_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_redirection_logs"   "redirection_id"    "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_redirection_logs"   "module_id" "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_redirection_logs"   "group_id"  "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_mf_custom_fields"   "custom_group_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_banner_dealerships" "post_id"   "Not indexed"
"pr_main"   "wp_redirection_groups" "module_id" "Not indexed"
```

Can I run this query for each missing index?

ALTER TABLE work_incident ADD INDEX `ReportID` (ReportID);

Or do I need to make additional checks? I don't think any disaster can come from it even if it's not needed, but I just want to make doubly sure.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't submit this question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: *Can I run this query for each missing index?* No. Only one index can be used for one copy of a table used in the query. Therefore, creating a heap of indexes with one column each does not make sense. You should create composite indexes (those that include an expression containing a list of columns), one index per table.

Comment: Of course the optimal index for definite query and definite table may differ from the optimal index for the same table but another query. You must find the balance between SELECT queries performance and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries performance - so you should create only those indices which optimizes the most critical queries, or optimizes a lot of queries at the same time. Sometimes create one composite index with 2 columns is more useful than create 3-4 indies with 3-4 columns each (above 2 columns as first ones and different columns as a tail).

Comment: What do you mean by "Safe"?  In what way would creating an index be unsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* blindly add indexes for unindexed columns.

In addition to (or possibly redundant with) what Vesa says...

Maintaining indexes is extra work when `INSERTing`, `UPDATEing`, and `DELETEing`.  On the other hand, having an appropriate index significantly helps certain `SELECTs`.

The other indexes are wasted.

In WP, `postmeta` has a sloppy set of indexed.  This plugin fixes that table (and other meta tables):  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/  With that, performance is improved by removing, changing, and adding *selected* single_column *and multi-column* indexes.

There are many cases where a `SELECT` is helped by a single-column index but helped more by a multi-column index.  (This is called a "composite" index.)  Your approach to adding an index to `wp_postmeta` for `post_id` is such an example.  The plugin deliberately avoids that single-column index, preferring a multi-column index.

More on construction 'optimal' indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Another problem with blindly adding index:  There is a limit of 16 indexes per table.

Comment: Is it ok to add indexes to wp_options wp_posts wp_postmeta wp_comments wp_usermeta wp_termmeta?

Comment: @haher - It is _possible_ to add indexes to any wp table.  But is it useful?  I bring up one case where it is not the best.  The plugin has located the main inefficiencies in WP and fixed them in an optimal way.  (We may find more things to do later.)

Comment: Is there a way to do what that wp plugin does, but manually?

Comment: @haher - This discusses the main one (wp_postmeta):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 2):

Database indexing and optimization is a complex topic. Generally, it is safe to add indexes. However, it is probably not a good idea to add an index for each of the columns in your table. Each index that exists against a table always requires additional storage space on the server, and adds overhead to operations that change data: INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

So, indexes help query performance, but they also create overhead on data updates. Designing efficient indexing for you table requires you to consider the trade-offs.

To be able to design reasonable indexing, you should have a pretty good idea on what are the queries against the table. You should know which queries are run the most frequently, and which queries are taking the most time. And when looking at the queries, you should consider which columns are the queries SELECTing, and which columns are used as conditions in the WHERE clause. Both of them matter.

Suppose you queries are returning all or most columns of the table. In that case, when the server executes your query, it will probably use just ONE INDEX to narrow down the set of rows that need to be read from the main table, and then use that information to read the necessary rows from the main table. In that case, it doesn't help to have many indexes, you just need the one that gives you the most benefit. The more SELECTIVE this one index is, the better. Suppose you have a query that uses two columns in the WHERE clause and an equals condition for both of the columns. Then the most selective index for that particular query would be an index that contains both of those columns. So, it's good to remember that you can have indexes that contain more than one column.

And for those indexes that have multiple columns, the order of the columns matters. When using the index, it's first using the column that is defined as the first column, then the second, etc. If you happened to have a query that has equals (=) condition for column A and greater than condition (>) for column B, then you want to define the index [A, B], so A first, as that is the most selective. If the conditions were the other way around, you might also want to define the columns in the index in the opposite order.

Then you can also consider cases where your query SELECTs only a few columns from the table. Suppose you only need to return three columns from the table in your results, columns A, B, and C. And suppose you have two columns in the WHERE condition, one of them that also appears in the results, B, and another one that doesn't, column D. Then you might consider adding index for example for columns [B, D, A, C]. To be able to produce your result, the server would ONLY need to read data from your index, and not even go read anything from the main table at all. That might be way more efficient than anything else, for that particular query. (the columns might also go [D, B, A, C], depending on the conditions and the data of the columns, but anyway columns in the WHERE clause should go first in some order, and columns in SELECT after them.)

This is by no means a comprehensive guide to index design, but hopefully gives you some ideas on things to consider.

Comment: I agree with most of what you say.  But I need to point out one common misconception.  In the case of `WHERE A=1 AND B=2` the order of the columns in `INDEX(A,B)` does _not_ matter.  My "proof":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239658/higher-cardinality-column-first-in-an-index-when-involving-a-range

Comment: The "[B,D,C,A]" example is called "covering".  If D is tested with `=` and B is tested with `<`, then D should come before B.  (Rule: Put all equal tests before any range tests.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I run this query for each missing index?

Only one index can be used for one copy of a table used in the query. Therefore, you can, but creating a heap of indexes with one column each does not make sense.

You should create composite indexes (those that include an expression containing a list of columns), one index per table.

Of course the optimal index for definite query and definite table may differ from the optimal index for the same table but another query. You must find the balance between SELECT queries performance and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries performance - so you should create only those indices which optimizes the most critical queries, or optimizes a lot of queries at the same time.

Sometimes create one composite index with 2 columns is more useful than create 3-4 indices with 3-4 columns each (above 2 columns as first ones and different columns as a tail). Or create one of these 3-4 column indices - another queries may use prefix part of this index.